# QML - addressing an ancestor

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qtquick2

I have a container which is being filled with dynamically created components during runtime. Each of those elements (let's call them `DynamicObject`s) has a tree of subelements (`Node`s), also created dynamically. What is more, The `Node` components can be nested inside one another (like a tree structure).

Let the container have the `id` parameter set to `"main_container"` and every `DynamicObject` have it set to `"dynamic_object"`.

Whenever I try to address the `main_container` from any of the nested `Node` elements it all works fine. The problem is when I try to address the `dynamic_object` from any `Node` other than the root one (the one being the direct descendant / child of the `dynamic_object`). It results in:

> ReferenceError: dynamic_object is not defined

**My question is:** what might be the cause behind this behaviour? Can it have something to do with the fact those objects are dynamically created? (that was my first thought since I can always address the `main_container` and it is statically declared in the qml code).

**Code example:** (if there is anything missing please let me now in the comments)

```
// Container.qml

import "container_logic.js" as Logic

Rectangle {
  id: main_container

  Keys.onTabPressed: {
    Logic.createComponent("DynamicObject.qml", {/* some parameters */});
    var dynamic_object = Logic.object;

    Logic.createComponent("Node.qml",{labelText: "asdefg"}, undefined, dynamic_object)
    var asdefg = Logic.object;
    Logic.createComponent("Node.qml",{labelText: "tree A"}, undefined, dynamic_object)
    var tree_a = Logic.object;

    Logic.createComponent("Node.qml",{labelText: "a"}, undefined, asdefg)
    var a = Logic.object;
    Logic.createComponent("Node.qml",{labelText: "s"}, undefined, asdefg)
    var s = Logic.object;

    asdefg.subnodes = [a, s]

    Logic.createComponent("Node.qml",{labelText: "tree B", isInput: false}, undefined, dynamic_object)
    var tree_b = Logic.object;
    Logic.createComponent("Node.qml",{labelText: "xyz", isInput: false}, undefined, dynamic_object)
    var xyz = Logic.object;

    Logic.createComponent("Node.qml",{labelText: "x", isInput: false}, undefined, xyz)
    var x = Logic.object;
    Logic.createComponent("Node.qml",{labelText: "y", isInput: false}, undefined, xyz)
    var y = Logic.object;
    Logic.createComponent("Node.qml",{labelText: "z", isInput: false}, undefined, xyz)
    var z = Logic.object;

    xyz.subnodes = [x,y,z]

    dynamic_object.treeLeft = [asdefg, tree_a]
    dynamic_object.treeRight = [tree_b, xyz]
  }
}

// DynamicObject.qml

Rectangle {
  id: dynamic_object

  property alias treeLeft : tree_left.subnodes
  property alias treeRight: tree_right.subnodes

  Rectangle {
    id: content_area

    Node {
      id: tree_left

      labelText: "left"

      anchors.left: parent.left
    }

    Node {
      id: tree_right

      labelText: "right"

      anchors.right: parent.right
    }
  }
}

// Node.qml

ColumnLayout {
  id: node

  default property alias subnodes: subnodes_area.data
  property alias labelText: label.text

  Rectangle {
    id: header_area

    Text {
      id: label
    }

    MouseArea {
      id: mouse_area

      anchors.fill: parent

      hoverEnabled: true
      onHoveredChanged: {
        console.debug(main_container) // works fine
        console.debug(dynamic_object) // **generates the error for all nodes but the root one**
      }
    }
  }

  ColumnLayout {
    id: subnodes_area

    anchors.top: header_area.bottom
  }
}

// container_logic

var component = null
var owner = main_container
var object = null
var data = null

function createComponent(type, info, callback, container) {
  callback = callback || finishComponent
  owner = container || main_container

  if(component != null) {
    console.log("Error: a component is being loaded at this time");
    return;
  }

  component = Qt.createComponent(type)
  data = info

  if(component.status === Component.Ready) {
    callback()
  } else if(component.status === Component.Loading) {
    component.statusChanged.connect(callback)
  } else {
    console.log("Error loading component:", component.errorString())
  }
}

function finishComponent() {
  if(component.status === Component.Ready) {
    object = component.createObject(owner, data)
    if(object === null) {
      console.log("Error creating object")
    }
  } else if(component.status === Component.Error) {
    console.log("Error loading component:", component.errorString())
  }
  resetData()
}

function resetData() {
  component = null;
  data = null;
}
```

Comment: Can you show a simple example so that we can understand better what you're trying to do ?

Comment: done, hope I didn't forget any crucial part and that it will clarify what my intentions are

Comment: Are you giving all the dynamic objects the same id?

Comment: Yeah. I could try and assign different ids to the dynamic objects, but that would probably require adding a readonly property that would be set to the dynamic object itself (so that it's components were able to use it's properties). Still I don't think this is the source of the problem since each `Node` should be able to see it's ancestor `DynamicObject` via the `dynamic_object` id. At least that would be my guess. If that was the reason behind all of this then I guess the root `Node`s also shouldn't be able to reference the parent `DynamicObject`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdeclarativedynamicobjects.html :

> - If Qt.createComponent() is used, the creation context is the QDeclarativeContext in which this method is called
> - If a Component{} item is defined and createObject() is called on that item, the creation context is the context in which the Component is defined

The problem was that the `createComponent()` function for each subsequent `Node` was called from the context of the `main_container`, thus preventing the descendants from being able to resolve the `dynamic_object` id.

Solved it by moving the code responsible for creating the nested `Node`s to the `Node.qml` file (actually to a javascript file imported by that qml document, but the result is the same).